# Contractions in やんなっちゃう

Tags: contractions

A person is comparing herself to some disreputable school mates, thinking that she might be similar to them, and says:

> やんなっちゃうなぁ

Is this a contraction of (い)やになっちゃうなぁ meaning "I ended up becoming unlikeable"?

I'm coming across more and more of these contractions as I read more, and they keep tripping me up. Are there any general rules I should know that will help me figure this stuff out on my own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, やんなっちゃう is short for いやになっちゃう, which is short for いやになってしまう.

いやになる is a fixed phrase meaning "to be fed up / sick / disgusted". So やんなっちゃうなあ is something like "Now I'm starting to feel disgusted", "I can't help being sick".

Comment: "To become an unlikeable person" is いやな人になる, by the way.