# Siri says そわそわしてしまいます

Tags: grammar

Siri asked to set a timer responds with:

> １分セットしました。そわそわしてしまいます。

1. Is the latter part correct (I assume so)?
2. If it means "I'm all nervous" (I guess the English counterpart is "Ok, it's set. And the suspense is killing me") -- why isn't it simply そわそわしています?
3. My dictionary of grammar lists two usages of てしまう: (1) to express regret; (2) to express doing something to the end -- the latter is explicitly mentioned to be possible in future tense, but the example given is to complete a certain action before another one starts (先に食事をしてしまってください).

   How is てしまう used here? It's a state + しまう. Are there more examples of this usage (maybe I'm missing some common form which I did not pay attention to when spoken by humans)?

Comment: Does this help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30442/9831 "can't help feeling" ? or maybe this: http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E8%80%83%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86

Comment: But both examples are pretty negative, so I would put them in the "regret" drawer. Does it work for phrases like ワクワクしてしまいます or 楽しみしてしまいます?

Comment: そわそわ is more like "restless", so... I don't think it's so positive as ワクワク or 楽しみにする. ワクワクしてしまいます might be okay in some situations but 楽しみにしてしまいます is a bit odd.

Comment: @Chocolate So you mean Siri is actually grumbling? That may be the root cause for my confusion. I was expecting something in the "excitedly waiting"-style.

Comment: I wouldn't call it grumbling... してしまう as "can't help" doesn't always sound that negative.

Comment: @Chocolate I meant そわそわ is not the state of curious expectation. ...yes, I guess mackygoo's answer described it well.

Comment: Right... そわそわ is like 落ち着かない and isn't really a state of curious expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> そわそわしてしまいます。
>   Is the latter part correct (I assume so)?

質問の意味が「Siriの応答をあなたが正しく聞き取ったのか」なら、たぶん正しく聞き取ったでしょう。
「Siriの応答は正しいか」なら、Siriの設計者に聞いてみなければわからない。しかし、十分あり得ます。一般に「そわそわする」とは、**慣れないこと、あるいは自信のないことに対して落ち着かない様子**を表します。ここで、Siri設計者がこの表現を使ったのは、通常ならタイマーはもっと長い時間（数十分とか数時間とか）を設定するのに、この度は１分という短い時間なので、誤差を入れると、「１分経過を正確に伝えられるか、緊張するなぁ」という人間っぽい気持ちを表現したかったからだと想像します。しかし、これではSiri側の気持ちは表せますが、Siriにタイマーをセットした人には、本当に大丈夫かなという不安が残ります。たぶん私なら、「お任｛まか｝せください。でも緊張するなぁ。」とでも応答するように設計するでしょう。

> If it means "I'm all nervous" (I guess the English counterpart is "Ok, it's set. And the suspense is killing me") -- why isn't it simply そわそわしています?

「そわそわしています」は現在進行形だが、Siriの応答は「１分経過を正確に伝えられるか、緊張するなぁ」という「ちょっと困った状態に**なった**」ことを表現したいので、「しています」ではなく「してしまう」を使っている。辞書の説明にある(1) to express regretに近いが、"It is a bit embarrassing that I got into such a state"というような意味かと思います。決して(2) to express doing something to the endではありません。

> How is てしまう used here? It's a state + しまう. Are there more examples of this usage ;

「困ったなぁ」という状況 It is a bit embarrassing that I got into such a state に近い表現の例としては、

そんなに見つめられると、

- 恥ずかしくなってしまいます。
- 困ってしまいます。
- 恥ずかしいので、黙ってしまいます。
- 恥ずかしいので、うつむいてしまいます。

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes, it's correct.
2. そわそわしてしまいます sounds more natural than そわそわしています here; the latter is like just describing your state rather objectively ("I'm being restless" -- or,  it could also sound like "I look restless"), whereas the former is more like "I can't help feeling restless (because of that)." "It makes me feel restless (regardless of whether I like it or not)."
3. I think ～ています or ～ちゃう has a few more meanings. The ～てしまう here means "can't help ~~ing."

An example from Shogakukan's Progressive Japanese-English Dictionary:

> 今日結果がわかると思うと**そわそわしてしまう**。
>   I *can't help being on tenterhooks* when I think that I'll find out the results today.

The dictionary also gives "restless", "fidgety", and "in a state of nervous excitement" as translations of そわそわ.

A few examples of this てしまう:

> - イライラしてしまいます。 I can't help feeling irritated.
> - ～～と思ってしまいます。 I can't help but think...

Comment: @naruto うわあすげえうちまつがひ... ありがとうございます <m(__)m>

Answer (score 0):

> Siri asked to set a timer responds with:
>
> > １分セットしました。そわそわしてしまいます。
>
> Is the latter part correct (I assume so)?
>   (......) why isn't it simply そわそわしています?

Without further context, そわそわします is the natural expression. We need more context to know the need to say してしまう. However, it's subjective. It's the matter of what the speaker feels.

You can think of てしまう as て終{しま}う. It's about completion/perfect aspect. Because of this sense of completion, it's also used to express a feeling of regret. In Japanese, we use tense forms regardless of time; we don't differentiate verb forms depending on past, present, or future, but rather if it's completed or not. We differentiate tense by other expressions or by the context. So, you can use てしまう for a future event as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what further context you expect. I was talking about Siri - Apple's digital assistant - you ask it to set the timer and it replies with the quoted phrase. That's all.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what the machine is thinking when it says that. XD